# Minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{C}$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $m \in \mathbb{C}$ be integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

The definition I use: $m\in \mathbb{C}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f(m)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m)=0$.

Comment: That's usually taken as the definition of integral element (the polynomial must be monic, though). How did you define integrality? Also, what did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Is monicity implicit in you definition of "minimal polynomial"?

Comment: $ m \in \mathbb{C}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ if there exists a monic polynomial $f(m)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m) = 0$.

Comment: ya. monicity is required in the definition of monic polynomial

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You know that there is a monic polynomial $f \in \Bbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(m) = 0$. All you have to do is factor $f$ in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$, apply the [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)#Implications), and check that the factors must be monic, too.